# windbg source code debug ,can not see local variable in locals window

Tags: c++, debugging, local, windbg

I am using  windbg to process a remote debug, everything is ok, i can use  f10 or f11 to step debug. My debug eviroment is win7,language is c++.
there's one problem ,i can not see the local varialbe in function , it  shows as the following picture.

why is this situation happened? in my opinion , if i can see all registers of the process , i must can see the local variables of bRet.

can some one help me? thanks a lot.

Here is the code

```
bool CNBAGFxFont::Init() 
{ 
    bool bret = true;
    m_pFontlib = *new GFxFontLib(); 
    if (m_pFontlib) 
    { 
        bret = m_pFontlib->Init(); 
    }
    if (!bret) 
    {
          m_pFontlib = NULL;
          m_pGFxLoader->SetFontProvider(NULL); 
          return bret; 
    } 
    //m_pFontMC = *m_pGFxLoader->CreateMovie("gfxfontlib.swf");
    //m_pFontlib->AddFontsFrom(m_pFontMC, true)
  }
```

[here is the screen shot when debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewn3a.png)

Comment: bool CNBAGFxFont::Init()
{
  bool bret = true;
  m_pFontlib = *new GFxFontLib();
  if (m_pFontlib)
  {
   bret = m_pFontlib->Init();
  }
  
  if (!bret)
  {
   m_pFontlib = NULL;
   m_pGFxLoader->SetFontProvider(NULL);
   return bret;
  }
  //m_pFontMC = *m_pGFxLoader->CreateMovie("gfxfontlib.swf");
  //m_pFontlib->AddFontsFrom(m_pFontMC, true);    here is the code , i don't know how to format .  when is debugging ,i can not see the value of bRet .

Comment: in the class ,the locals window can only show the private member

Comment: Are you building with any optimization?  If so, the compiler is likely not actually allocating any `bret` variable.  Also, you're not returning anything when `bret == true`.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot - it helps.  You're in the right window (View > Locals), and you *should* see "bret" (which is a local variable).  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Rebuild, redownload and re-test (to make sure your debuggers .exe image is in sych with the actual executing image), 2) Review the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  Please post back what you find.  ALSO: "optimization" can be bad.  Look here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/debugging-optimized-codenew-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: @paulsm4, thanks a lot , i will do this  immediately。

Comment: @Michael Burr - I like your thinking: you might be right.  Per [this](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/debugging-optimized-codenew-in-visual-studio-2012/), MSVS 2012 Update 3 or higher might enable MSVS (and WinDbg) to debug optimized code, if compiled with `/Zo`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr , oops , it's just this problem , if i disabled the optimization , the windbg works ,and can see the local variables in the window。How many things does the compiler do if the optimiztion is opened? can soem explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

The program was compiled with optimization.

From OP's comment:

> If I disabled the optimization, WinDbg works and I can see the local variables in the window